# Question regarding Lebesgue Integrability in $\sigma$ -finite spaces

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm taking a course in measure theory and we defined integrability in a $\sigma$
 -finite space as follows: Suppose $\left(X,\mathcal{F},\mu\right)$
  is a $\sigma$-finite measure space, a measurable function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$
  is said to be integrable on $X$ (denoted $f\in L^{1}\left(X,\mathcal{F},\mu\right)$) if for every collection $\left\{ X_{m}\right\} _{m=1}^{\infty}$
  such that $X_{m}\uparrow X$
 , $X_{m}\in\mathcal{F}$
  and $\mu\left(X_{m}\right)<\infty$
  the following apply:

1. $f$
   is integrable on every set $A\subseteq X$
   such that $\mu\left(A\right)<\infty$
   .
2. The limit $\lim\limits _{m\to\infty}\int_{X_{m}}\left|f\right|d\mu$
   exists and does not depend on the choice of $\left\{ X_{m}\right\} _{m=1}^{\infty}$
   .
3. The limit $\lim\limits _{m\to\infty}\int_{X_{m}}fd\mu$
   does not depend on the choice of $\left\{ X_{m}\right\} _{m=1}^{\infty}$
   .

If said conditions apply then we define $\int_{X}fd\mu=\lim\limits _{m\to\infty}\int_{X_{m}}\left|f\right|d\mu$

Now suppose $\mathcal{G}\subseteq\mathcal{F}$
  is a $\sigma$
 -algebra on $X$
 . Let $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$
  be a $\mathcal{G}$
 -measurable function such that $f\in L^{1}\left(X,\mathcal{G},\mu\right)$
 , is $f$
  necessarily in $L^{1}\left(X,\mathcal{F},\mu\right)$
  ? 
Obviously $\mathcal{G}$
 -measurability implies $\mathcal{F}$
 -measurability but what about integrability?

**EDIT:** It seems the construction of the integral we did is quite unorthodox, I'll elaborate further on the definitions: Suppose $\left(X,\mathcal{F},\mu\right)$ is a measure space and let $A\subseteq X$ be a subset of finite measure. We define a simple function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ to be any function taking a countable collection of real values $\left\{ y_{n}\right\} _{n=1}^{\infty}$. Denote $A_{n}=\left\{ x\in A\,|\, f\left(x\right)=y_{n}\right\}$. Assuming $f$ is measurable we say that $f$ is integrable on $A$ if the series ${\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\displaystyle y_{n}\mu\left(A_{n}\right)}}$ is absolutely convergent in which case we define: $$\int_{A}fd\mu={\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}y_{n}\mu\left(A_{n}\right)$$
Furthermore, given any measurable function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ we say $f$ is integrable on $A$ if there is a sequence of simple functions (as defined) which are integrable on $A$ and converging uniformly to $f$ on $A$. In which case we define:  $$\int_{A}fd\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{A}f_{n}d\mu$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In point 1., applying $\mu$ to $A$ implies that $A \in \mathcal{F}$? And how is integrability on $A$ defined then to not be circular?

Comment: @DanielFischer I've added further elaborations to the definitions. Apparently integrability on $\left(X,\mathcal{G},\mu\right)$ should almost immediately imply integrability on $\left(X,\mathcal{F},\mu\right)$ but I don't really see why.

Comment: 2 always holds on a bigger sigma algebra monotone convergence, though i am unsure if this or monotone convergence is more trivial. I am thinking why 3 must be true.

Comment: @Lost1 Existence of the limit in 2 always implies existence of the limit in 3, uniqueness might be in question. How do you use monotone convergence to obtain existence of 2 on a bigger sigma-algebra?

Comment: I've given it a bit more thought and I think it would suffice to show that given $A\in\mathcal{F}$ such that $\mu\left(A\right)<\infty$ there is a $ B\in\mathcal{G}$ such that $\mu\left(B\right)<\infty$ and $ A\subseteq B$. I can't seem to manage to show this though...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I will be more than happy to be corrected.

The limit must be unique for 2. The reason is that you may write the integral

$\int_{A_n} |f| = \int_X |f|1_{A_n}$. (1)

The integrand of the rhs is monotonically increasing, hence must have the same limit as putting the limit inside the integral by monotone convergence theorem. This is independent of the sets you choose as long they tend up to X so must be unique.

For 3, just use the fact $\int f = \int f^+ - \int f^-$ and apply 2.

I am somewhat unsatisfied with this argument. It feels wrong or i habve somehow cheated using Monotonce Convergence Theorem.

Comment: It looks like a sound argument, I think it works :)
I wonder if there's a more elementary argument as to why it might be a direct result of the definition without having to resort to MCT.

Comment: @Serpahimz yes me too. It feels like cheating

Comment: @Serpahimz i think you could try to bound the sets in the bigger sigma algebra by ones in the smaller one to sandwich every possible sequence of An, but this looks like more work i am willing to do.